# Foreign Keys error in Yii 1.1.15

Tags: php, mysql, yii, foreign-keys, database-migration

I add Foreign Keys to my app. There I have tables for `comments`, `games`, `films` and `books`. When I create comment for games, I set field `game_id` to the ID of current game, but appears this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`chooseone`.`tbl_comments`, CONSTRAINT `FK_books_comments` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_books` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_comments` (`content`, `game_id`, `author_id`, `created`, `updated`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4)
```

I already find related posts, and try do some changes(e.g.change `INT(10)` in table `comments` into `INT(11)` etc.), but error still here. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What are tthe fields types in which you want to add a foreign key(both of them)

Comment: So, this two fields have the same type? It will be better to show structure of 2 tables and query

Comment: @sergio, yes, the types id of books, films and games is equal to the book_id, film_id and game_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message contains all the information you need for this problem:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

The above indicates that the problem is in the child row (which is generally going to be the case when inserting.)

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_books_comments` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) 
REFERENCES `tbl_books` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE).
```

The SQL statement executed was:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_comments` (`content`, `game_id`, `author_id`, `created`, `updated`) 
VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4)
```

Look at the constraint. You MUST have a `book_id` in any rows in the `tbl_comments` table, and that `book_id` MUST match the `id` of a record in the `tbl_books` table. You however do not include a `book_id` in the insert statement.

Specify the `book_id` to resolve this issue.

Comment: I set DEFAULT NULL option for book_id in my migrations and now all works fine. Thanks!